# How can one simplify iterated sums $\sum\sum\dots$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, soft-question, combinatorial-number-theory

**Question.** I am interested in whether there are methods to simplify a term with iterated $\sum$s in it where the range of one $\sum$-symbol may depend on a variables of the preceding $\sum$-symbols.

**Example.** In particular I am interested in this example: $$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{ \lfloor\frac{n}{3} \rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-3i}{2} \rfloor} 1.$$
How can one express $f(n)$ with a simpler formula, without the $\sum$-symbols and without the variables $i$ and $j$ occuring in it?

Comment: Note that for any $n$ we have $\Sigma_{j=0}^n1 = n+1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{ \lfloor\frac{n}{3} \rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-3i}{2} \rfloor} 1=\sum_{i=0}^{ \lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor}\left(\lfloor \frac{n-3i}{2} \rfloor+1\right).$$
Now consider $n=6q+r$ with $r=0,1,2,3,4,5$. For example if $r=0$ then
\begin{align*}
f(n)&=\sum_{i=0}^{ 2q}\left(\lfloor \frac{6q-3i}{2} \rfloor+1\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{q}\left(\lfloor \frac{6q-3(2j)}{2} \rfloor+1\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{q}\left(\lfloor \frac{6q-3(2j-1)}{2} \rfloor+1\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{q}\left(3(q-j)+1\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{q}\left(3(q-j)+1) +1\right)=6\sum_{j=0}^{q}j+q+1-3q +2q\\
&=3q^2+3q+1.
\end{align*}

Finally, you should verify that
$$f(n)=\mbox{round}\left(\frac{(n+3)^2}{12}\right)\tag{1}$$
see the OEIS sequence [A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399).

P.S. Note that for $n=6q$, formula (1) holds
$$f(n)=\mbox{round}\left(\frac{(6q+3)^2}{12}\right)=\mbox{round}\left(3q^2+3q+3/4\right)=3q^2+3q+1.$$

Comment: I've already noted this. But how does this help me with finding a formula without any $\sum$-symbol in it and without the variable $i$ occuring in it?

Comment: Ah, I see you edited the question. Could you explain the "which can be simplified easily" part? For me it is not that obvious.

Comment: Also, I think you forgot the floor in $\sum_{j=0}^{q}\left(3(q-j)+1\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{q}\left(3(q-j)+1) +1\right)$

Comment: RobertZ: What do you mean by "new line"?

Comment: No floor there. The floor is already calculated! $\lfloor \frac{6q-3(2j)}{2} \rfloor=3(q-j)$

Comment: @user463033 Any further doubt? BTW if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thanks, I have to think about it.

Comment: To derive formula (1), did you need to consider each of the six cases r = 0, 1, ..., 5?

Comment: @user463033 Yes, but they are all very similar.

Comment: And how did you guess to consider exactly the remainders modulo *6*?

Comment: @user463033 Because inside the floors we divide by $3$ and by $2$.

Comment: You mean in $\lfloor \frac{n-3i}{2} \rfloor$ and $\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor$?

Comment: @user463033 Yes I mean that

Answer (score 0):

I'll use your example, with $n=8$. (But I'll ignore your summand "1" because that makes an explicit sum trivial.)

The first sum has $i$ running $0$ to $2$. When $i=0$, $j$ runs $0$ to $4$. When $i=1$, $j$ runs $0$ to $2$. When $i=2$, $j$ runs $0$ to $1$. So visuzalise your $(i,j)$ plane:

`4 |*
3 |*
2 |* *
1 |* * *
0 |* * *
- + - - -
  | 0 1 2`

So in the end here you have $10$ terms to sum. Their positioning in the $(i,j)$ plane is a little erratic, and this means you are in general unlikely to be able to simplify expressions like this if the summand is complicated. (Of course you can simplify it with a fixed $n$. But what I mean is for an unknown $n$, the positioning of the terms that contribute is not typically "regular" enough to give you a simplified formula in $n$.)

Sometimes you can make progress by reversing the order of summation. To do that, you still need the visualization above. Now $j$ would run first from $0$ to $4$. And you need $i$ to run from $0$ to some function $f$ of $j$ where $f(0)=2$, $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=1$, $f(3)=0$, and  $f(4)=0$. It's not immediately clear how to write a formula for such a function here. But sometimes, with other double sums, it is clear how to do that.

Comment: If the sum with "1" as the summand is trivial, why don't you give a formula for that? That would be what I am asking for. Instead you are in my opinion rather explaining what $\sum_{i=0}^{ \lfloor\frac{n}{3} \rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-3i}{2} \rfloor} 1$ means than answering my question ...

Comment: If that is what you want, the previous answer gives you that. I was answering what I thought was your question, which is the thing you boldfaced as "Question". If you are actually asking what is the sum of that specific double sum, then how about making that your "Question"? Something you boldface as "Example" can serve to clarify your question, but your question is still your "Question", right? If I ask, "how do you add $m+n$? You know, like $5+10$?" I am asking how to add in general, not how specifically to add $5$ and $10$.